# sympy differential equation of harmonic oscillator

Tags: python, sympy

I am here because I've been trying to solve a differential equation using sympy and unfortunately I've not succeed so far. What I've done so far is:

1) inserting the differential equation, assigning the values and solving it:

```
import sympy as sp
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sp.init_printing()

F0=sp.symbols('F0')
Wd=sp.symbols('Wd')
A=sp.symbols('A')
B=sp.symbols('B')
x=sp.Function('x')
t=sp.symbols('t')

eq=sp.Eq(x(t).diff(t,2)+A*x(t).diff(t)+(B**2)*x(t),F0*sp.cos(Wd*t))
display(eq)
```

[image: Equation 1]

```
sol=sp.dsolve(eq,x(t)).rhs
display(sol)
```

[image: Contents of <code>sol</code>]

2) Afterwards I substitute the values of all declared symbols , set the initial conditions so that I can clear the equation

```
consts = {A:  0.1, 
      B:  0.01,
      F0:  0.0,
      Wd: 0.01,
      }

sol=sp.simplify(sol.subs(consts))
display(sol)

x0=5

#to evaluate initial conditions - x(0)
cnd0=sp.Eq(sol.subs(t,0),x0)
C1 = sp.symbols("C1") 
sol_c1=sp.solve([cnd0],(C1))

display(sol_c1)

C2s=sp.simplify(sol.subs(sol_c1))
display(C2s)
```

[image: C2s]

3) Then I repeat the same process to the first derivate. The point with this is to calculate the values C1 and C2 from x(0) and X'(0). Here goes the code

```
sold=sp.diff(sol,t)
display(sold)

xd0=0
#to evaluate initial conditions - derivative x'(0)
cnd1=sp.Eq(sold.subs(t,0),xd0)
sold_c1=sp.solve([cnd1],(C1))

display(sold_c1)

C2d=sp.simplify(sol.subs(sold_c1))
display(C2d)
```

[image: C2d]

4) When I try to build the equation with C2s and C2d and solve it in order to finally get an equation where C2 is dependent of t, python throws an error. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `F0 = 0` your differential equation becomes a homogeneous equation.
`C1` and `C2` are **constants** of integration. So, I don't think they should be functions of `t`. The two initial conditions on `x(0)` and `x'(0)` give two equations in `C1` and `C2` which we can solve.

```
import sympy as sp
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sp.init_printing()

F0=sp.symbols('F0')
Wd=sp.symbols('W_d')
A=sp.symbols('A')
B=sp.symbols('B')
x=sp.Function('x')
t=sp.symbols('t')

eq=sp.Eq(x(t).diff(t,2)+A*x(t).diff(t)+(B**2)*x(t),F0*sp.cos(Wd*t))
display(eq)

sol=sp.dsolve(eq,x(t)).rhs # x(t)
display(sol)

sold=sp.diff(sol,t) # x'(t)
display(sold)

consts = {A:  0.1,
      B:  0.01,
      F0:  0.0,
      Wd: 0.01,
      }

sol=sp.simplify(sol.subs(consts))
display(sol)

sold=sp.simplify(sold.subs(consts))
display(sold)

x0=5
#to evaluate initial conditions - x(0)
cnd0=sp.Eq(sol.subs(t,0),x0)

xd0=0
#to evaluate initial conditions - derivative x'(0)
cnd1=sp.Eq(sold.subs(t,0),xd0)

c1c2 = sp.linsolve([cnd0,cnd1],sp.var('C1,C2'))
display(c1c2)
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood anything about your differential equation.

Comment: Hello Amit. Yes, that is exactly I was looking for. I was really confused with C1 and C2 but your answer cleared up my question. Thanks a lot !